# problem with usestate in firebase to save data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, foreach, use-state

I have a problem that I can not solve try a thousand ways and nothing

I happen to show

I generate a state:

```
 const [totalComidas, setTotalComidas] = useState({})
```

After that I do a useEffect to bring me the data from firebase and I want to save it in the state but it saves it empty

```
useEffect(() => {

    const resultadoComidas = []
    db.collection('menu semanal')
    .get()
    .then((snap) => {
        snap.forEach((doc) => {
           const comida = doc.data()
        //    comida.id = doc.id
           resultadoComidas.push(comida)
           console.log(resultadoComidas[0])
        })
        setTotalComidas(resultadoComidas)
        console.log(totalComidas) 
    })    
}, [])
```

And these are my results in console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pw9c.png)

The first result in the console is before adding it to the state and the second is the new state, which seems strange to me because it brings the data correctly but when I assign it to the state it assigns it to me empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for the `totalComidas` to be empty when you log it inside `useEffect` because the result of your `setTotalComidas` won't be showed in that particular `useEffect`. If you want to see the change of your `totalComidas` you need to have another `useEffect` like so

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(totalComidas)
})
```

If you wonder why this is the case then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately). It explains the behavior of `useEffect`